# Firebase/Android: what to include to use AdMob package

Tags: android, firebase, admob, google-play-services

What should be included to use AdMob after the Firebase integration?

is it enough this:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.2'
```

or should this still be included?

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2'
```

Comment: Do not use both of them together. This will increase your dex method count. If you are using firebase, just use "compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.2'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.2'` for integrating adMob using firebase.

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2'` will not include firebase integration.

Comment: so, don't need this anymore?  `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2'`

Comment: If your project is already having adds than just change the library and link your project with firebase from firebase console.Add either of them.Don't use both .